# How to play a .ts file in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video, itunes

I want to play .ts file in iPhone, so

1. I have been trying to copy it to iTunes but it is not allowing to copy to iTunes movies, then I converted it to .mp4 and tried again, it copied.

So converted file is working but file should not be converted.

2. I sent it through mail and tried to download it, but it is showing "These types of attachment cant be accessed on this device."

Does iPhone supports the file type or not?

Comment: have you tried the things that were mentioned on this post?
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166578/how-to-watch-a-ts-video-file-on-an-ipad

Comment: @Linuxuser07 it is saying to use the third parties and they will convert and play, but here I want to play it on native player.